# Enter number in scientific notation, convert to Integral in Haskell

Tags: haskell, casting

Looking here:
https://hackage.haskell.org/package/scientific

And here:
https://wiki.haskell.org/Converting_numbers

I would expect to be able to enter a number as a string in Scientific notation

```
Prelude Data.Scientific> read "1e100" :: Scientific
1.0e100
```

And convert into integer like so:

```
Prelude Data.Scientific> (read "1e100" :: Scientific ) :: Int

<interactive>:7:2: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘Int’ with actual type ‘Scientific’
    • In the expression: (read "1e100" :: Scientific) :: Int
      In an equation for ‘it’: it = (read "1e100" :: Scientific) :: Int
```

This does not seem to work.  How can I convert my Scientific type into an integer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use `toUnboundedInteger` (or maybe `toBoundedInteger`, I not sure what the bound `10^e` is referring to). The signature is:

```
toUnboundedInteger :: Scientific -> Maybe Integer
```

So, informally, the function checks checks if the `Scientific` parameters is actually an integer (for instance it could be a float). If it is a float the result returned is `Nothing` otherwise it is `Just` the integer you expect.

Comment: I think this solution is not valid because `toUnboundedInteger` doesn´t exist in the Scientific package, and if you use `toBoundedInteger` you cannot get the `Maybe Integer` because an `Integer` doesn't satisfy the `Bounded` constraint.